Graph API call to permanently delete file throwing ODataError: 'One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.'
I need to permanently delete a file from a Sharepoint Online document library using the MS Graph API. This is working fine in Graph API explorer:
Graph Request
In C#, I am getting this error for the same request:
await graphClient.Drives["{Library_Drive_ID}"].Items["{Item_Drive_ID}"].PermanentDelete.PostAsync();


Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: one of the provided arguments is not acceptable.

I am using Azure AD app with Application permission Sites.Fullcontrol and Sites.ReadWrite.
What needs to be corrected to fix the issue?
Exception message
API Permission

What is the item you are trying to delete? Is it a document, or a folder?

Its a document.

Please edit your question and add more details in it like your complete code to make it clear

Hi @Sridevi, I added the permission Files.ReadWrite.All but facing the same error as before. I am using the same code logic that you have provided in response.

Could you add that API permissions Portal image and error image by editing your question?

Hi @Avi Any update?

Added the error message and API permissions. However, I am able to use the DeleteAsync method to delete the file (which moves to the recycle bin).

Could you confirm whether you are using same c# code as I mentioned in answer? Please edit your question and add your Program.cs code

While using client credentials flow to permanently delete file, make sure to grant Files.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type as below:

I have one file named Document.docx in sridoclib drive of DemoSite like this:

To permanently delete above file from a SharePoint Online document library using the MS Graph API, make use of below sample C# code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        var driveId = "driveId";
        var itemId = "itemId";

        try
        {
            await graphClient.Drives[driveId]
                             .Items[itemId]
                             .PermanentDelete
                             .PostAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Item permanently deleted.");
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Graph API Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().FullName}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in SharePoint Portal where file deleted permanently as below:

Recycle bin:

Reference:
Permanently delete a file or folder - Microsoft Graph v1.0
